# JS toLocaleString always show currency symbol regardless of locale

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, currency

I can format currencies that use a dollar sign (pesos, Canadian dollars, Australian dollars) based on locale using `toLocaleString` but if the locale matches the currency, no indicator is given which currency is shown.

What I'm getting:

```
// US Currency to US Locale
(1234.56).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}); //$1,234.56
// AU Currency to AU Locale
(1234.56).toLocaleString('en-AU', {style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD'}); //$1,234.56
// US currency to AU locale
(1234.56).toLocaleString('en-AU', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}); //US$1,234.56
```

What I'd like:

```
// US Currency to US Locale
(1234.56).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}); //US$1,234.56
// AU Currency to AU Locale
(1234.56).toLocaleString('en-AU', {style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD'}); //A$1,234.56
```

Is there a way to make it always show the currency type indicator? I'm using user-passed variables for locale and currency.

Comment: when I run your commands in the chrome browser console I am seeing what you are excepting for AUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add `currencyDisplay: 'code'` to your options object.

This dosen't give you exactly the formatting you're looking for (USD100, as opposed to US$100) but it should always let your users know explicitly what type of currency they're dealing with, even when the currency matches the locale.